# How to add text to an open Dialog window?

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog

I am working on a Google Sheets macro that displays some text to the user, then presents some buttons for the user to interact with. The buttons run another function and I am struggling with how to have the button display the text to the user.

I can't find the method or object I am supposed to use to grab the currently open window and edit the html to add more text. Or if that isn't possible, how can I close the open window and then display a new window that also has the old text?

```js
function example(text,title,height=90,width=350) {
  const dialogbutton = '<br><input type="button" value="Do Stuff" onClick="google.script.run.doStuff();" />'
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text+dialogbutton).setHeight(height).setWidth(width)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, title);
}
function doStuff() {
  const dialogWindow = ???//I am hoping to retrieve the open window as an object
  const text = getText() //run some other function and get the new text to insert
  dialogWindow.displayedText += text //modify the displayed window to add the new text
}
```

Comment: User presses button and does something the function that does something returns a message back to the onSuccessHandler and the onSuccess can display to a section of the page that displays messages to the user.  Perhaps it's id is msg.

Comment: If you wish to clear the msg after a short time you can send another google.script.run from inside success handler and call a function called delay which waits a few second and the returns back to the next successHandler and you can clear the message then.  There other ways as well.  You could have set a timeout function to clear the msg box after a short delay.

Comment: @Cooper I'm very new to Javascript and Apps Script, could you show me how to do that with code?

Comment: I could but it's pretty simple and there is no better time to start learning than right now.  Here's a [Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and of course there is [google-apps-script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)  BTW one of the reasons that we now where to find what we are locking for in the documentation is because most us I would guess refer to the documentation often when we are coding.  There's no point in trying to remember everything when you don't have to.

Comment: @Cooper I appreciate the links to the documentation, but my problem is that I don't know where to look. I don't know what objects or methods to use to accomplish the suggestion you made. you said `onSuccessHandler`, how would I write code to add text to the current window using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of how to communicate with the server (i.e. Spreadsheet or Doc).  In this case a spreadsheet with Sheet1!A1 = hello

Here is a simple dialog

[image]

Server side code Code.gs bound to a spreadsheet

```
function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Simple");
  html = html.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}

function doStuff() {
  try {
    // let get a value from spreadsheet
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    return sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in doStuff() "+err);
  }
}
```

HTML Page HTML_Simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Do Stuff" onClick="doStuffOnClick()">
    <input type="text" id="whatStuff">
    <script>
      function doStuffOnClick() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function(response) {
              document.getElementById("whatStuff").value = response;
            }
          ).doStuff();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference

- [HTML Service Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)
- [google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative and will help me move forward in my project. Is there a way to have `response` show up below the button "Do Stuff" in the same window? Or is it only possible to make a new window to display the response?

Comment: I've edited my HTML_Simple.html to show how to display the response.  But this is very basic HTML.  I would suggest you also look at [javascript and HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)

Comment: You are a Wiz! Thanks for your help. I have learned a lot from your answer.